# Why is the Information Management Policy Settings link missing in blank sites?

Tags: information-management

In SharePoint Server 2010, when I create a new "Blank Site" site collection, I don't have the Information Management Policy Settings link on the Document content type setting page.  The only way I can make the link appear is to enable the Library and Folder Based Retention feature.

If I create a site based on the Team Site site definition, the link is there by default (without the feature activated).

Is this a normal behavior?  A bug?  How can I have the Information Management Policy Settings link in a Blank site without activating the Library and Folder Based Retention feature?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please tag by feature or topic and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The "Blank Site" has a lot of normal things stripped out of the site definition.  There are some scenarios where it may not be a good idea to create sites using the Blank site template.  I've moved away from it for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Its the normal behaviour of SharePoint and its not a bug. The Blank Site template just has the minimum features or libraries to start with. If you need the Blank Site with the information management policy feature on, or any other customization, then it would go for creating a custom site definition.

Answer (score 0):

I know that for some reason you don't want to activate features to enable the link to appear--I honestly think you are just making your life WAY more complicated than it needs to be.  But anyhow, for anyone else out there who stumbles on this thread because they are wondering why the link is not there in their blank site, you can make it appear by activating  In Place Records Management in Site Collection Features.

Answer (score 0):

On a site that was created from the Blank Site template (STS#1), 'Publishing Infrastructure' feature needs to be enabled to have the 'Information management policy settings' and 'Record declaration settings' links to show on the List/Library settings pages.

Also 'Manage Lists' permission must be present.